# Ruby Character Creation for text RPG

Tags: ruby, text

First I just wanted to state I am very new to Ruby. I am a hug fan of Dnd and I wanted to create a text adventure game based off of Dnd rules. The issue I am having (I don't even know if it is possible) is that I am creating a character class and I want the variables assigned outside the class. The reason for this is I don't want the player to have to type:

```
character.new("Havatr", "elf", "tall and lean", "etc")
```

This is just an experiment before actually creating the file. This is what i have so far:

```
class Character
  attr_reader :name, :race, :description

  def initalize (name, race, description)
    @name = name
    @race = race
    @description = description  
  end
end

def prompt
  print "Enter Command >"
end

puts "What is your name?"
prompt; next_move = gets.chomp.downcase

puts "what is your race?"
prompt; next_move = gets.chomp.downcase

puts "What do you look like?"
prompt; next_move = gets.chomp.downcase

player_one = Character.new("#{a}","#{b}","#{c}")
print player_one
```

If there is a way to do this can I get assistance with it and if there is a better method then what I am trying please let me know. The idea behind this is to try and dump the class into a yaml file to create a character save.

When I run the code this is what it looks like:

```
What is your name?
Enter Command > Havatr
What is your race?
Enter Command > Elf
What do you look like?
Enter Command > I look like me 
C://core_rules0.0.1/Characters.rb:27:in '': undefined local variable or method 'a' for main:Object (NameError)
```

Comment: If you have another question, create it as a new question. And if an answer solved your problem, select it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here. The first is that you misspelled `initialize`. The second is that instead of saving the values entered by the user in `a`, `b`, and `c` you save each in `next_move`. That's an easy fix:

```
puts "What is your name?"
prompt; name = gets.chomp.downcase

puts "What is your race?"
prompt; race = gets.chomp.downcase

puts "What do you look like?"
prompt; desc = gets.chomp.downcase

player_one = Character.new(name, race, desc)
print player_one
```

You'll notice that I did `Character.new(name, race, desc)` instead of `Character.new("#{a}", "#{b}", "#{c}")`. First, I used more descriptive names (one-character variable names are almost always a poor choice, except for well-known conventions like `i` to represent the iteration number in a loop). Second, I did `name` instead of `"#{name}"` because the latter doesn't actually do anything. `#{...}` is *string interpolation* in Ruby. It's a way to put values into a string, e.g. `"Hello #{name}"`. But when you don't have anything else in the string, as in `"#{name}"`, it doesn't do anything except convert `a` to a string—a task for which `name.to_s` is a better solution, and which is unnecessary anyway because we know `name` is already a string. `"#{whatever}"` is *always* unnecessary; `whatever.to_s` is *sometimes* necessary.

The other thing you'll notice is that `print player_one` prints something like:

```
#<Character:0x007fc23b88bf08>
```

...which maybe isn't what you expected. That's because Ruby doesn't know how to print your Character object in a human-readable way. You can tell it how by defining a `to_s` method. For example:

```
class Character
  # ...

  def to_s
    "#{name} (#{race} - #{desc})"
  end
end
```

For the inputs in your question, this would yield the following:

```
puts player_one
# => havatr (elf - i look like me)
```

(It's all lower-case because you called `downcase` on each input, which may or may not be the behavior you actually want.)

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. The only thing i am running into now is it is placing on the screen        #Character(0x21a04b8). Is there a way to convert this?

Comment: Thank you for all your help i have post another part of my question above.

Comment: That is beyond the scope of your original question. Please post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a simple bug here:

```
class Character
   attr_reader :name, :race, :description

   def initalize (name, race, description)
     @name = name
     @race = race
     @description = description  
   end
 end

 def prompt
   print "Enter Command >"
 end

 puts "What is your name?"
 prompt; a = gets.chomp.downcase
 puts "what is your race?"
 prompt; b = gets.chomp.downcase
 puts "What do you look like?"
 prompt; c = gets.chomp.downcase

 player_one = Character.new("#{a}","#{b}","#{c}")
 print player_one
```

You were setting the results of the prompt to the variable `next_move`